# Python Error:No module Name Scripts

Tags: python

I'm running Python 2.7 in my Ubuntu 16.0. I have created a folder Scripts & put 2 files,

config.py &  **init**.py

, inside that folder. Also I have added in updated .bashrc pythonpath using following statement

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:path to my script folder
```

But while I'm ruining `from Scripts import test`  I'm getting error message `ImportError: No module named 'Scripts'`
Can you please suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your module placed ? You have to add the folder where your module present to sys path. You can do that by adding below lines in your python file

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/your/module")
```

Comment: Sandeep,as per your suggestion I have updated my code. Here is my updated code `import sys
sys.path.append("/path to my Scripts folder")
from Scripts import test as con` But still I'm getting same error

Comment: can you paste your sys.path.append line in your code ?

Comment: sys.path.append("/home/christ/Scripts")

Comment: You are trying to import module Sciprts , so use `sys.path.append("/home/christ") `